# Ensure another Observable emitted first, before doing an network request but provide the response as cold observable (with replay) to the consumers

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

What i want to achieve:
I have a `FeaturesService` that should provide the information if a certain feature is enabled by providing different `Promises`.
The list of enabled features is provided as json object via an HTTP API (see `DataService`).
Before the HTTP request to get the list of features is send, we need to make sure the user is authenticated first (see `AuthService`).
Furthermore:

- The features request should only be made as soon as someone uses one of the `Promises` provided by the `FeaturesService` (e.g. `isFeatureXSupported`), not necessarily on start of the application or as soon as the user is authenticated. (**cold observable?**)
- The features HTTP request should only hit the network once, and should be cached (replayed) afterwards

What I have come up with so far:

```
import { Subject, Observable, ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";
import { map, shareReplay, switchMap, take } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Container, injectable } from "inversify";
import "reflect-metadata";

interface DtoFeatures {
  supportedFeatures: string[];
}

@injectable()
class AuthService {
  private authenticated$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

  public authenticate(): void {
    // Mock code
    console.log("Authenticate Request (Mock) started");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Authenticate Request (Mock) finished");
      this.authenticated$.next(true);
    }, 100);
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticated$.asObservable();
  }
}

@injectable()
class DataService {
  public getFeatures(): Observable<DtoFeatures> {
    // Mock Code, real HTTP Request happening instead that needs to be authorized
    console.log("Network Request (Mock) started");
    const features$ = new Subject<DtoFeatures>();
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Network Request (Mock) finished");
      features$.next({ supportedFeatures: ["featureX"] });
      features$.complete();
    }, 150);
    return features$;
  }
}

@injectable()
class FeaturesService {

  // private readonly dtoFeatures: Observable<DtoFeatures> = this.authService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
  //   take(1),
  //   switchMap(() => this.dataService.getFeatures()),
  //   shareReplay(1)
  // );

  private readonly dtoFeatures: Observable<DtoFeatures> = this.dataService.getFeatures().pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  public supportedFeatures: Promise<string[]> = this.dtoFeatures.pipe(
    map((features) => features.supportedFeatures)
  ).toPromise();

  public isFeatureXSupported: Promise<boolean> = this.supportedFeatures.then(
    (features) => features.some((x) => x === "featureX")
  );

  public isFeatureYSupported: Promise<boolean> = this.supportedFeatures.then(
    (features) => features.some((x) => x === "featureY")
  );
}

@injectable()
class App {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private featureService: FeaturesService
  ) {
    console.log("App initialized");
    this.authService.authenticate();
    this.featureService.isFeatureXSupported.then((x) => console.log(`FeatureX enabled: ${x}`));
  }
}

// Configure DI
var container = new Container();
container.bind<AuthService>(AuthService).toSelf();
container.bind<DataService>(DataService).toSelf();
container.bind<FeaturesService>(FeaturesService).toSelf();
container.bind<App>(App).toSelf();

// Initialize App
container.resolve(App);
```

Link to the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cerf-t43mi?file=/src/index.ts

The given code covers most of the requirements, except the problem, that the features request happens before the user was authenticated.

Console logs:

```
>Network Request (Mock) started <-- Problem!
>App initialized 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) started 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) finished 
>Network Request (Mock) finished 
>FeatureX enabled: true
```

So I tried this version instead, but then no feature request at all is happening:

```
class FeaturesService {

  private readonly dtoFeatures: Observable<DtoFeatures> = this.authService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
     take(1),
     switchMap(() => this.dataService.getFeatures()),
     shareReplay(1)
  );

  // private readonly dtoFeatures: Observable<DtoFeatures> = this.dataService.getFeatures().pipe(
  //   shareReplay(1)
  // );

  ...
}
```

Console logs:

```
>App initialized 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) started 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) finished
```

I guess i am mixing up something related to cold / hot observables here, but i can not figure out the problem. I would really appreciate any help and i think this is a nice real world use case for `rxjs`/`reactive programming`, so maybe also other would like to know how to achieve it.

Comment: Why do use `toPromise()`? Why do want to work with `Promises`? If your source or the Api you're working with returns an Observable it's always preferred to continue working with Observables than calling `toPromise()` on them.

Comment: From consumer perspective i think it is easier to work with a promise. First you do not expect a stream of values but one and second you can use async / await e.g.
`await this.featuresService.isFeatureXSupported`

Comment: I think it's not advisable to switch to Promises if you already work with an HTTP Api that returns Observables. An Observable that emits once and completes is perfectly fine. Working with Observables all the way will give you with more flexibility down the road.

Comment: Even when i switch to observable all the way, the issue is still the same:
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-smoke-p67yr?file=/src/index.ts
I would love to understand where the conceptual error is in the code...

Comment: The problem is that multiple instances of `AuthService` are created. `inRequestScope()` should fix this. Use `container.bind<AuthService>(AuthService).toSelf().inRequestScope()`

Comment: Oh yes *face palm* you are totally right. Should have read the documentation of the DI framework better... I just managed to build the working examples with Observables all the way. If the consumer uses `.toPromise()` he can profit from async / await etc.
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-sammet-z1x2r?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [fridoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9423231/fridoo) for the answer!

First problem was the wrong DI configuration, you need to use `.inRequestScope()`
or `.inSingletonScope()` when registering the services e.g.:

```
container.bind<AuthService>(AuthService).toSelf().inRequestScope();
```

Seconds problem was using `.toPromise()` in the `FeaturesService`. This was causing the network request to be done even when there was no consumers of the features service.
By using Observables all the way it works as expected. The consumer can also use `.toPromise()` when he wants to use async / await.

Full code example:

```
import { Subject, Observable, ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";
import { map, shareReplay, switchMap, take } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Container, injectable } from "inversify";
import "reflect-metadata";

interface DtoFeatures {
  supportedFeatures: string[];
}

@injectable()
class AuthService {
  private authenticated$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);

  public authenticate(): void {
    // Mock code
    console.log("Authenticate Request (Mock) started");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Authenticate Request (Mock) finished");
      this.authenticated$.next(true);
    }, 100);
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticated$.asObservable();
  }
}

@injectable()
class DataService {
  public getFeatures(): Observable<DtoFeatures> {
    // Mock Code, real HTTP Request happening instead that needs to be authorized
    console.log("Network Request (Mock) started");
    const features$ = new Subject<DtoFeatures>();
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Network Request (Mock) finished");
      features$.next({ supportedFeatures: ["featureX"] });
      features$.complete();
    }, 150);
    return features$;
  }
}

@injectable()
class FeaturesService {

  private readonly dtoFeatures: Observable<DtoFeatures> = this.authService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(() => this.dataService.getFeatures()),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  public supportedFeatures: Observable<string[]> = this.dtoFeatures.pipe(
    map((features) => features.supportedFeatures)
  );

  public isFeatureXSupported: Observable<boolean> = this.supportedFeatures.pipe(
    map((features) => features.some((x) => x === "featureX"))
  );

  public isFeatureYSupported: Observable<boolean> = this.supportedFeatures.pipe(
    map((features) => features.some((x) => x === "featureY"))
  );
}

@injectable()
class App {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private featureService: FeaturesService
  ) {
    console.log("App initialized");
    this.authService.authenticate();

    // Comment this line out, to see that there is no (mocked) network request for features
    this.featureService.isFeatureXSupported.subscribe((x) => console.log(`FeatureX enabled: ${x}`));
    
    // Build promise at consumer level:
    // this.featureService.isFeatureXSupported.toPromise().then((x) => console.log(`FeatureX enabled: ${x}`));
  }
}

// Configure DI
var container = new Container();
container.bind<AuthService>(AuthService).toSelf().inRequestScope();
container.bind<DataService>(DataService).toSelf().inRequestScope();
container.bind<FeaturesService>(FeaturesService).toSelf().inRequestScope();
container.bind<App>(App).toSelf();

// Initialize App
container.resolve(App);
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-sammet-z1x2r?file=/src/index.ts

Console logs (with a consumer):

```
>App initialized 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) started 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) finished 
>Network Request (Mock) started 
>Network Request (Mock) finished 
>FeatureX enabled: true
```

Console logs (without a consumer):

```
>App initialized 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) started 
>Authenticate Request (Mock) finished
```